# Translating Delphi code to C# (Blowfish)

Tags: c#, delphi, encryption, blowfish, encryption-symmetric

I'm not a develloper Delphi, but i must transform this delphi code to C#:

```
Function EncodeClave(Clave:String):String;
 var
   R: String;
   FStringFormat:Integer;
 begin
   FStringFormat:=4196;
 with TCipher_Blowfish.Create('CLAVE', nil) do
  try
    Mode := TCipherMode(0);
    R := CodeString(Clave, paEncode, FStringFormat);
    Result := R;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
 end;
```

I have found the following sites in my research:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

and

http://www.schneier.com/code/blowfish.cs

I don't understand the line :

```
FStringFormat:=4196;
```

Why is there a predefine size of the format?  Is there another transformation with blowfish (DECUtil) ?

and the mode :

```
Mode := TCipherMode(0);
```

in the delphi source of Cipher

> (http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidE1F5EC890EF9FD7D5FFEB524898B00BC8403B799.aspx)
>   the parameter 'mode' have the following order :
>   cmCTS, cmCBC, cmCFB, cmOFB, cmECB, cmCTSMAC, cmCBCMAC, cmCFBMAC

So I suppose in delphi the mode 0 is cmCTS ... but in reality I don't know.

an example of result : user : ADMIN pass : ADMIN ---> pass : fAtP3sk=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `FStringFormat` variable (4196) is equal to use the `fmtMIME64` const defined in the *[DECUtil](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid3A096DAFAC89AB57E0A0C6D0E32761283D0516D7.aspx)* unit which is defined like so

```
 fmtMIME64      = $1064;     // MIME Base 64
```

This value is used to format the string passed to the CodeString method. in this case the line

```
 R := CodeString(Clave, paEncode, FStringFormat);
```

returns the value of the `Clave` variable in the MIME Base 64 format.

Now about the line

Mode := TCipherMode(0);

you are setting the the Mode property to the first value of the enumeration.

```
 TCipherMode = (cmCTS, cmCBC, cmCFB, cmOFB, cmECB, cmCTSMAC, cmCBCMAC, cmCFBMAC);
```

in this case is equivalent to write.

```
Mode := cmCTS;
```

Comment: @Gilles: `$` means hex in Delphi, so it's `0x1064` in C#, which is 4196 decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at source for the Delphi Object [TCipher_Blowfish](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid2115DA85B11A0ED7F92F8CA29DD530C16FC9C96D.aspx) there are some constants declared for the String Format.

```
fmtMIME64      = $1064;     // MIME Base 64
```

A "$" defines a hex number in delphi so $1064 = 4196 being used in your sample code.

TCipherMode(0);

TCipherMode is a reference to the following enumerated type:

```
TCipherMode = (cmCTS, cmCBC, cmCFB, cmOFB, cmECB, cmCTSMAC, cmCBCMAC, cmCFBMAC);
```

So TCipherMode(0) = cmCTS

The code is a little easier to understand if you make those replacements:

```
Function EncodeClave(InputString:String):String;
 var
   BlowfishObj: TCipher_Blowfish;
 begin

  BlowfishObj := TCipher_Blowfish.Create('CLAVE', nil);
  try

    BlowfishObj.Mode := cmCTS;  // (Cipher Text Stealing)
    Result := BlowfishObj.CodeString(InputString, paEncode, fmtMIME64);

  finally
    BlowfishObj.Free;
  end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var 
  FStringFormat: Integer; 
begin 
  FStringFormat := 4196;
```

is the same as

```
Int32 FStringFormat; 
FStringFormat = 4196;
```

in C#.

`FMode := TCipherMode(0);`' is a typecase of an integer to an enumeration value. Delphi enumerations are pretty much the same as those in C#; by default, they start at `0`, so an enumeration of

```
type
  TCipherMode = ( cmCTS, cmCBC, cmCFB, cmOFB, cmECB, cmCTSMAC, cmCBCMAC, cmCFBMAC);
```

would mean that `cmCTS` has a numeric value of `0`, `cmCBC` 1, and so forth.

The code should have properly been written

```
FMode := cmCTS;
```

which is not only less characters to type, but is much clearer for those reading it in the future (like you). :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
FStringFormat:=4196;
```

This is purely just assigning a value to a variable, `FStringFormat` is an integer value that was declared and now you are giving it a value.

Answer (score 0):

in first thank for all answers !!

I don't know if i can post the solution here, but if maybe i can help anyone ...

finaly i have transformed the delphi code to DLL like this :

```
library crypto;

   uses
  Cipher in '\Source\Cipher.pas',
  DECUtil in '\Source\DECUtil.pas',
  Hash in '\Source\Hash.pas',
  SysUtils;

{$R *.res}

Function EncodeClave(Clave:String):String;
var
  R: String;
  FStringFormat:Integer;
begin
  FStringFormat:=4196;
  with TCipher_Blowfish.Create('CLAVE', nil) do
  try
    Mode := TCipherMode(0);
    R := CodeString(Clave, paEncode, FStringFormat);
    Result := R;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

function MsgEncode(pIn: PWideChar; out pOut: PWideChar): LongBool; stdcall;
var
  sOut: string;
  BuffSize: Integer;
begin
  sOut := EncodeClave(pIn);
  BuffSize := SizeOf(Char)*(Length(sOut)+1);
  GetMem(pOut, BuffSize);
  FillChar(pOut^, BuffSize, 0);
  Result := Length(sOut)>0;
  if Result then
    Move(PChar(sOut)^, pOut^, BuffSize);
end;

procedure BlockFree(p: Pointer); stdcall;
begin
  FreeMem(p);
end;

exports
  MsgEncode,
  BlockFree;

begin
end.
```

and use this DLL in C# like this :

```
class Program
    {
        [DllImport("crypto.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool MsgEncode(string pIn, out IntPtr pOut);

        [DllImport("crypto.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void BlockFree(IntPtr p);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr pOut;

            string encode = "admin";
            string encoded = "";


            if (MsgEncode(encode, out pOut))
                encoded = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pOut);
            BlockFree(pOut);

            Console.WriteLine("String Encoded '" + encode + "' : " + encoded);
        }
```

it's not super clean but do the job ...